# Cant set Virtual host with Xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, virtualhost

i am trying to set my Virtual Hosts.

This is setting for my **Hosts** File

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.0.1       test.local
```

And this is my setting in **httpd-Vhosts.Conf** file

```
 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test"
ServerName http://test.local/
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common</VirtualHost>
```

And this is the error i am getting here,

```
  Server error!

 The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.      Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

 If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
 Error 500
```

I have already enabled this line

```
  Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

but i dont know what i am missing here to create a virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test"
ServerName test.local
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

There are two issues that might prevent Apache from correctly interpreting your file:

- `</VirtualHost>` has to be in a new line, otherwise Apache can't parse the file (`Syntax error`)
- The `ServerName` is usually put there without `http://` and the trailing slash

(Furthermore you shouldn't use `.local` as this might interfere with some network stuff.)

Comment: </VirtualHost> is already in new line for some reason i was unable to paste it in new line here.
Also i tried to remove http:// and trailing slash still no hope

Comment: Did you restart Apache? What does the Apache error log say (should be somewhere in `<xampp-dir>\apache\logs\error.log`)?